# Excel-VBA: run increments in same column depending on neighbouring column

Tags: vba, tuples, increment

it's sounds tricky and it is!

I have an example. I am trying to fill out the red values automatically
[image]

As you can see, column A and column B make a tuple and these tuples need to get incremented numbers.

While coding I feel like I am running out of functions to do this. I would be glad for hints, about even how to approach this problem the best!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

Put this in C1:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1,$B$1:B1,B1)
```

Then copy down

Comment: thank you, this is the almost perfect solution. unfortunately it doesn't work for empty cells in column B. in this case it would always put zero. see remarks here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842